# What would quantitative meter sound like?

Tags: meter

Here are my terms: http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780198715443.001.0001/acref-9780198715443-e-719#

Problem is, Greek and Latin seem to be fairly dead — or at least it's difficult to trust someone who says he knows how Homer would have been read. I'm wondering (a) whether one *would* notice the difference between quantitative and, e.g., accentual meter, and, if so, (b) what the former would sound like.

Edit (didn't realize it was locked; here's the entry from the link):

> "The pattern of measured sound-units recurring more or less regularly
>   in lines of verse. Poetry may be composed according to one of four
>   principal metrical systems:
>
> (i) in quantitative metre, used in Greek and Latin, the pattern is a
>   sequence of long and short syllables counted in groups known as feet
>   (see foot, quantitative verse);
>
> (ii) in syllabic metre, as in French and Japanese, the pattern
>   comprises a fixed number of syllables in the line (see syllabic
>   verse);
>
> (iii) in accentual metre (or ‘strong-stress metre’), found in Old
>   English and in later English popular verse, the pattern is a regular
>   number of stressed syllables in the line or group of lines, regardless
>   of the number of unstressed syllables (see accentual verse);
>
> (iv) in accentual-syllabic metre, the pattern consists of a regular
>   number of stressed syllables appropriately arranged within a fixed
>   total number of syllables in the line (with permissible variations
>   including feminine endings), both stressed and unstressed syllables
>   being counted (see accentual-syllabic verse).
>
> The fourth system—accentual-syllabic metre—is the one found in most
>   English verse in the literary tradition since Chaucer; some flexible
>   uses of it incline towards the accentual system. However, the
>   descriptive terms most commonly used to analyse it have, confusingly,
>   been inherited from the vocabulary of the very different Greek and
>   Latin quantitative system. Thus the various English metres are named
>   after the classical feet that their groupings of stressed and
>   unstressed syllables resemble, and the length of a metrical line is
>   still often expressed in terms of the number of feet it contains: a
>   dimeter has two feet, a trimeter three, a tetrameter four, a
>   pentameter five, a hexameter six, and a heptameter seven. A simpler
>   and often more accurate method of description is to refer to lines in
>   either accentual or accentual-syllabic metre according to the number
>   of stressed syllables: thus an English tetrameter is a ‘four-stress
>   line’, a pentameter a ‘five-stress line’ (these being the commonest
>   lines in English). English accentual-syllabic metres fall into two
>   groups, according to the way in which stressed (●) and unstressed (○)
>   syllables alternate: in duple metres, stressed syllables alternate
>   more or less regularly with single unstressed syllables, and so the
>   line is traditionally described as a sequence of disyllabic
>   (2-syllable) feet; while in triple metres, stressed syllables
>   alternate with pairs of unstressed syllables, and the line is seen as
>   a sequence of trisyllabic (3-syllable) feet.
>
> Of the two duple metres, by far the more common in English is the
>   iambic metre, in which the stressed syllables are for the most part
>   perceived as following the unstressed syllables with which they
>   alternate (○●○●○● etc.), although some variations on this pattern are
>   accepted. In traditional analysis by feet, iambic verse is said to be
>   composed predominantly of iambs (○●). This iambic pentameter by John
>   Dryden illustrates the metre:
>
> And doom’d to death, though fated not to die. The other duple metre,
>   used in English less frequently than the iambic, is trochaic metre, in
>   which the iambic pattern is reversed so that the stressed syllables
>   are felt to be preceding the unstressed syllables with which they
>   alternate (●○●○●○ etc.); in terms of classical feet, trochaic verse is
>   said to be made up predominantly of trochees (●○). This trochaic
>   tetrameter from Longfellow illustrates the metre: Dark behind it rose
>   the forest It is common, though, for poets using trochaic metre to
>   begin and end the line on a stressed syllable (see catalectic), as in
>   Blake’s line: Tyger, tyger, burning bright In such cases it is hard to
>   distinguish trochaic and iambic metres. The triple metres are far less
>   common in English, although sometimes found. In dactylic metre, named
>   after the dactyl (●○○), the stressed syllables are felt to precede the
>   intervening pairs of unstressed syllables: Cannon in front of them
>   (Tennyson: dactylic dimeter) In anapaestic metre, named after the
>   anapaest (○○●), the pattern is reversed: Of your fainting, dispirited
>   race (Arnold: anapaestic trimeter) Dactylic and anapaestic verse is
>   not usually composed purely of dactyls and anapaests, however: other
>   feet or additional syllables are frequently combined with or
>   substituted for them. All these patterns are open to different kinds
>   of variation, of which the most common is traditionally called
>   substitution of one foot for another (but see also demotion,
>   promotion); for the other feet sometimes mentioned in the context of
>   substitution, see foot. Other variations include the addition or
>   subtraction of syllables to alter the line’s length. The theory and
>   practice of metrical verse is known as prosody or metrics, while the
>   detailed analysis of the metrical pattern in lines of verse is called
>   scansion."

Chris Baldick Publisher: Oxford University Press Print Publication Date: 2015 Print ISBN-13: 9780198715443 Published online: 2015 Current Online Version: 2015

Comment: Unfortunately your link leads to the login page of the Oxford Reference subscription site, and not all of us have subscribed. Could you include the definitions in the text of your question please?

Comment: Native English speakers don't hear quantitative meter as meter. For one thing, English doesn't have long vowels. For another, English allows far more consonant clusters than Latin. Compare _Arma virumque canō, Trōiae quī prīmus ab ōrīs Ītaliam, fātō profugus, Lāvīniaque vēnit_ with _Meum est propositum in taberna mori, Ut sint vina proxima morientis ori_.  Stress was not an important thing to Greek or Latin poetry, but it is in English. However, Greek feet don't work on English bodies.